# Django reusable apps and namespace

Tags: python, django

My team is starting a new Django project.
We want to start using git submodules in our new project. We've used submodules in previous projects and it worked great for us. The idea is to have apps, that we regularly use in projects, in a common folder as a git submodule.

Assume our git location is at git@mygit.git:repo-django

We have the apps (repo-django) in the root of the project like so:

```
/myproject
    repo-django/
        app1/
            models.py
        app2/
            models.py
        app3/
            models.py
```

There is some debate in the team around how to structure the packages and I can't find any guides on what would be considered the best option in this regard.

Should "**repo-django**" be added as a class path so that imports of the modules can be relative to the root of repo-django or should repo-django form part of the class paths?

To use the models for example:

```
from repo-django.app1.models import MyModel
```

we can add the app to django like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
  'repo-django.app1',
  'repo-django.app2',
  'repo-django.app3',
)
```

or if we add repo-django via:

```
sys.path.append("repo-django")
```

Then we can use the models like so

```
from app1.models import MyModel
```

...and add the apps to django like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
  'app1',
  'app2',
  'app3',
)
```

The big debate is around namespaces. One camp argues that putting all the reusable apps in **namespaces** is a good thing while the other camp argues that the apps will be less portable and too dependant on the folder name.

What would be the best approach and where can I find more information on this?